# How to calculate PDF given CDF? (and related problems)

Tags: probability

[image: PROBLEM]

I know how to find the CDF given the PDF. And I know that I must differentiate for this problem above, but I'm not sure how to go about solving these problems

Comment: You should define all of your terms, and type the full question out here.

Answer (score 1):

(a) What is a CDF?   You should have a list of properties that identify a function as a valid cumulative distribution function.   Which of these is affected by the value of term $a$?   What value of $a$ satisfies that property?

(b) Yes, indeed, differentiating the CDF will give the pdf **except** if there is a step discontinuity.   Check to see if that is the case, and take steps to deal with having a mixed distribution.

Answer (score -3):

The CDF, since it is the integral of the PDF, is always *continuous*.  Here that means that $\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{a- e^{-x}}{2}= \lim_{x\to 0^-} \frac{1}{2}x+ \frac{1}{2}$.  What does a have to be so those two limits are the same?

Comment: What about the CDF of any discrete distribution? Is it the integral of PDF? Is it continuous?

Comment: What is the **definition** of "CDF"?

Comment: CDF of r.v. $X$ is $F_X(x)=\mathbb P(X \leq x)$. Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function

Comment: It is possible to define a CDF for a mixed distribution such that the CDF is continuous and non-constant over some intervals but discontinuous at one or more points. It simply needs not to decrease. But there **is** a limit that needs to be satisfied by this particular CDF which this answer completely ignores, namely, $\lim_{x\to\infty} F_X(x)=1.$